# iOS 13 firebase is not working "The request timed out"

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, ios13

I am using the firebase with iOS 12 and lower version. its working perfectly. After that I update the iOS 13 beta and I tried the firebase. But unfortunately it's not working. I checked the log. Its like this

```
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out.
```

So I checked the firebase doc and they recently released the new version.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#6.5.0

So tried to update the pod file. But still firebase is installing 5.20.2

So my question is it possible to use two different version firebase sdk?

This is the pod file

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

And I am using the GeoFire as well. Still Geofire is require Firebase 5

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you internet connection is up and running?

Comment: @Adeel Yes 100% sure. Rest api are working. Only firebase is not working